# Floating divs with different heights are stucked while wrapping

Tags: html, css, height

Hello! Here is a problem: I have several (up to 5) divs with different heights. Inside those divs are portlets, which can grow in height. Here is a simplified example:

```css
.clz {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="clz">1111111111<br/>1111111111</div>
  <div class="clz">2222222222<br/>2222222222<br/>2222222222</div>
  <div class="clz">3333333333<br/>3333333333</div>
  <div class="clz">4444444444<br/>4444444444</div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eGawU/9/) is a JSFiddle, where you can see it.

When I decrease my browser window width, `div`s are wrapped, which is very good. The bad part is that `4444444444` is stuck at `2222222` - it does not fall to the start of the page:

```
1111111 2222222 333333
1111111 2222222 333333
        2222222 444444
                444444
```

Desirable behaviour is that when wrap occurs when `4444444` is placed at the beginning of the page at completely different line:

```
1111111 2222222 333333
1111111 2222222 333333
        2222222
4444444
4444444
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **display:inline-table** for this. Write like this:

```
.clz{
    display:inline-table;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/eGawU/13/

It's till IE8 & above

Comment: Super! Thank you very much! With additional `vertical-align: top;` everything is exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Depending on the behavior you're looking for and the browser support needed, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: this was the perfect solution.  Still worked for me 5 years later

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float. demo http://jsfiddle.net/eGawU/17/

Comment: That demo doesn't relate to simply removing the float? Remvoing the float from his original code will simply give you 100% width block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the first three divs in another `clz` div like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="clz">
        <div class="clz">1111111111<br/>1111111111</div>
        <div class="clz">2222222222<br/>2222222222<br/>2222222222</div>
        <div class="clz">3333333333<br/>3333333333</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clz">4444444444<br/>4444444444</div>
</div>​
```

This will make div 4 do exactly what you want, but you may have to nest more divs if you add more columns.

Comment: Not really an answer to my question, but, I guest, I can be misunderstood that way. 4444444 or 333333 - it does not matter to me. Question was about wrapping without problems from different heights, not wrapping of 4444444.

Answer (score 0):

use **Clear** Property of css

try this http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/eGawU/18/

**or**

you can add a extra div in below you want to break

try this http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/eGawU/19/

Comment: Not an answer to my question - wrapping depending on window size is what I want.